# How do I change the default screen when I have dual screen on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I reinstalled windows 7, and now the default monitor is on the right. I want it to be on the left. How do I set the default monitor to the one on the left ?

So far:

- I tried to unlock the task bar, and drag it on the left monitor, but all windows keep poping on the right. So I think there is a better way.
- I can physically switch the monitors, but there are a lot of cables and I don't want to get up from my chair.
- It is quite surprising, but switching the 2 DVI plugs on the graphic card does not change the default monitor.

For information (but I don't think it matters):

- Both screens are plugged in the graphic card by DVI, and are the same model (samsung P2370)
- The graphic card is a GeForce GTS 250. (with 2 DVI outputs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to:

**Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Display > Screen Resolution**

**(*or* right click on desktop > Screen resolution)**

There you'll see a graphic with your two monitors labelled "1" and "2".

Select the one labelled "2".

There's now an option:

> Make this my main display

Select that and hit "OK" or "Apply".

You should have switched the monitors over.

Answer (score 1):

you are 80% there already.

In Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution

- or

Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution

right below "Multiple Displays" you should see one of 2 items, **This is Your Main Display** or **Make This My Main display**
Selecting the graphical representation of the monitor and set what you want the "main Display" to be.  that will set what the system deems to be your "primary monitor"

The Number that the display is Identified as , has little to nothing to do with what is set as the main display monitor. Also the ID #  has little to nothing to do with what Port of the GPU it is on. It was just how the system put the monitors in Order, as they came in.  You have to mess with the registry to change that, and only severly organised people would worry about it .

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel > appearance and personalization > adjust resolution. If the screen on the left is your main display (labelled 1 in my case), and you have to move the arrow right to go left), click on screen 2 in the appaearnce of display image. After clicking on screen 2, scroll down below: "Multiple display", where there is an unchecked box labelled "Make this my display". Check that box, click "Apply" and then screen two (on the left becomes your main screen. Now uou're chilling