# What determines the primary display in a dual display desktop setup?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have two Dell displays connected to the [ASUS GTX 980 Strix](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics_Cards/STRIXGTX980DC2OC4GD5/) graphics card:

- **Landscape:** [Dell UltraSharp U2415](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&sku=860-BBDY)
- **Portrait:** [Dell UltraSharp U2312HM](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-u2312h/pd)

During boot all info is displayed on the portrait display and the image is turned by 90° so it's hard to use.

I’ve tried using different ports of my graphics card and even swapping input cables on my displays but the image is always displayed on the portrait-oriented display. Same on my previous card [ASUS GTX 660 Ti](https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/GTX660_TIDC2T2GD5/).

Any ideas on how to set the U2415 to be the main display?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/341165/how-do-i-change-the-default-screen-when-i-have-dual-screen-on-windows-7

Comment: @Chirag64 That's not a duplicate.  The other question refers to the displays in Windows, but this question refers to displays while in BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

Usually on graphics cards, primary display is DP > HDMI > DVI > VGA. If there are muliple DP, the first one is usually the one furthest away from DVI and HDMI.

Also, check your cables. Some cables are faster and may get signal to the monitor sooner.

As well, check BIOS to see if you can change settings for monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is highly video card dependant, it's often whichever port was successfully used last when only one monitor was attached.

So, working with that idea:

- Attach (only) one monitor (of your choice) to one of the ports (of your choice).
- Boot the system once.
- Then shut down and hook up the second monitor to the other port.
- Start up system again.

Comment: It did not help. Maybe the portrait display somehow responds faster during some kind of checkup?